# Golang split string by empty newline

Tags: regex, go

I have this JS function that I'm trying to translate to Go:

```
function splitByEmptyNewline(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')
    .split(/^\s*\n/gm);
}
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
func splitByEmptyNewline(str string) []string {
    strNormalized := regexp.
        MustCompile("\r\n").
        ReplaceAllString(str, "\n")
    return regexp.
        MustCompile("^s*\n").
        Split(strNormalized, -1)
}
```

This does not return the same result as the JavaScript version. So I'm wondering what I've missed?

I've tried using both double-quotes **"** and backward single-quotes **`** for the regex.

Comment: Can you make the JS one into a StackSnippet with sample input output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your seperator RegEx does not match because you split a complete string and the beginning of that string is not white-space. So instead of `^\s*\n` you must use `\n\s*\n`:

```
func splitByEmptyNewline(str string) []string {
    strNormalized := regexp.
        MustCompile("\r\n").
        ReplaceAllString(str, "\n")

    return regexp.
        MustCompile(`\n\s*\n`).
        Split(strNormalized, -1)

}
```

Here here is working example: https://play.golang.org/p/be6Mf3-XNP

Comment: Rather than a regular expression, why not simply [remove the windows return](https://play.golang.org/p/LMKcZqiOxWG)? `strNormalized := strings.Replace(str, "\r", "", -1)`